# Having trouble getting a list of users profiles

Tags: powershell, batch-file, profile

Greeting most amazing Community,

I am trying to come up with a script that will list all the profiles that are on a pc.
Example of the list I'd like:

```
Admin 
JSmith 
LGale 
Mthinker
```

---

Does anyone have any ideas how to even attempt to get the info or have a snippet of code they can share?

I have looked online and did some research and also look at lots of available scripts but nothing is quite when I need.

Comment: I'm downvoting because you _very clearly_ did not search google for "Windows list all profiles on PC," otherwise you would have found the answer immediately.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I am new and didnt know what to add. I corrected the post

Comment: My downvote is staying because, again, you clearly didn't research your question. (Also, "I tried a lot of things and nothing worked" is too broad to count. What are the _exact_ phrases you tried, and how did what you find not meet your needs?)

Comment: could it be as simple as: `@for /d %%i in (%homepath%\..\*) do @echo %%~nxi`

Comment: @Gerhard - I was actually thinking of just `net user`

Comment: @SomethingDark yes, but off topic questions does not need perfect answers/comments.

Comment: or should I say deserve.. ;)

Comment: This is much simpler done using the WMIC utility at the Command Prompt, e.g. `For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Assoc /AssocClass:Win32_UserProfile 2^> NUL')Do @Echo=%G`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to query WMI for [`Win32_UserProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ee886409(v=vs.85)) instances - each profile will be linked to the security identifier of the user owning the profile, which can in turn be translated to an account object with the user name:

```bsh
Get-CimInstance win32_userprofile |ForEach-Object {
  # Convert SID string to SecurityIdentifier object
  $SID = $_.SID -as [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]

  try {
    # Now we can resolve the actual account
    $SID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
  }
  catch {
    Write-Warning "Unable to translate SID '$($_.SID)' for profile at '$($_.LocalPath)' to account name"
  }
}
```

Which on my machine (with just one local account) lists:

```
COMPUTER-NAME\mathias
NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

Comment: Thank you. Where will this put the list?

Comment: @doheth Nowhere. You can assign the list to a variable if you want: `$listOfAccountNames = Get-CimInstance ...`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am new and will phrase my questions better in the future

Comment: An alternative methodology, _(which limits results to actual local normal user accounts)_, may be this one liner: `Get-CimInstance -Query "Select * From Win32_UserProfile Where Special != 'True' And LocalPath Is Not Null" | Select-Object -Property @{Label='UserNames';Expression={(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserAccount -Filter "SID = '$($_.SID)'").Name}}`.

Comment: @Compo filtering is definitely an excellent suggestion, but blindly querying `Win32_UserAccount` without knowing the environment, I'd very strongly recommend against :)

Comment: It's not blindly querying it, as you say, its passing it prefiltered SID's. Could you please explain where the problem may lie with such a methodology?